# What does (*[1 << 30]C.YourType) do exactly in CGo?

Tags: go, cgo

In the [Golang wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo), under "Turning C arrays into Go slices", there is a block of code that demonstrates how to create a Go slice backed by a C array.

```
import "C"
import "unsafe"
...
        var theCArray *C.YourType = C.getTheArray()
        length := C.getTheArrayLength()
        slice := (*[1 << 30]C.YourType)(unsafe.Pointer(theCArray))[:length:length]
```

Can anyone explain exactly what `(*[1 << 30]C.YourType)` does? How does it turn an `unsafe.Pointer` into a Go slice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`*[1 << 30]C.YourType` doesn't do anything itself, it's a type. Specifically, it's a pointer to an array of size `1 << 30`, of `C.YourType` values. The size is arbitrary, and only represents an upper bound that needs to be valid on the host system.

What you're doing in the third expression is a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).
This converts the `unsafe.Pointer` to a `*[1 << 30]C.YourType`.

Then, you're taking that converted array value, and turning it into a slice with a [full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) (Array values don't need to be dereferenced for a slice expression, so there is no need to prefix the value with a `*`, even though it is a pointer).

You could expand this out a bit like so:

```
// unsafe.Pointer to the C array
unsafePtr := unsafe.Pointer(theCArray)

// convert unsafePtr to a pointer of the type *[1 << 30]C.YourType
arrayPtr := (*[1 << 30]C.YourType)(unsafePtr)

// slice the array into a Go slice, with the same backing array
// as theCArray, making sure to specify the capacity as well as
// the length.
slice := arrayPtr[:length:length]
```

This construct has been replaced by a generalized [`unsafe.Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Slice) function in go1.17:

```
slice := unsafe.Slice(theCArray, length)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights! `[1<<30]` is used because the compiler rejects variable array bounds! So devs just pick a ridiculously large number!

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent: it's really just setting an upper bound for size. `1<<30` is often used in examples, because it's valid for both 32 and 64 bit systems, and it looks nicer than `1<<31-1`.

Comment: can the `length` bigger than `1<<30`?  or should I use `1<<63` on 64bit platform to make sure the index space is enough for access all the underlying data?

Comment: @HM.Yang, `length` can be anything up to what your system supports, so if you need more than `1<<30` bytes, then specify more than `1<<30` bytes. You will just have to use different source files for 32bit architectures, or limit building to 64bit only.

Comment: Note that starting with Go 1.17 one could use `unsafe.Slice` instead

Comment: thanks @EliBendersky, I've been updating these with the new function as I see them too ;)