# Go equivalent of void** from C

Tags: go, pointers, cgo

I need to call a **C** function which takes an argument of type `void**` from my **Go** code. What is the **Go** equivalent of `void**`? And how to properly pass it to the **C** function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out that `void**` is `*unsafe.Pointer`, and the `unsafe.Pointer` itself is `void*`.

Comment: You've found the right *type*. Getting the right *value* in the `void *` to which the `void **` points is another matter. If the C function you're calling *fills in* a `void *`, it provides the right value, but if it *uses* it instead or as well, you need to provide it a correct input.

Comment: @torek well, I have
```c
typedef unsigned char byte;

void foo(void** buffer) {
  *buffer = (byte*)malloc(32);

  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    byte* temp = (byte*)*buffer;
    temp[i] = i;
  }
}
```
And in my **Go** function I have `var buffer []byte`. How to pass the buffer to the function above so it could fill the buffer?

Comment: OK, you have the C function *fill in* the `void *` with a pointer to C memory, so you're good to go on the C side. However, the *Go* code wants a slice, and that's a bit of a problem because Go slices normally point to Go-allocated backing arrays. There are standard answers to that question, though; to see links to many of them, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61961793/1256452).