# How to iterate through a c-array

Tags: go, cgo

In go, I'm trying to iterate through an array that was created in C. I have the length of the array (`int arrc`) and its pointer (`mytype *arrv`).

I have found a way, but it involves transferring back and forth between go and c and is super super hacky.

```
// void *nextelement(void *p, int i, int size) {
//      return (void*)((uint64_t)p+i*size);
// }
#import "C"

...

    for i := 0; i < protoc; i++ {
        adr := (*C.mytype)(C.nextelement(unsafe.Pointer(myarr), C.int(i), C.sizeof_mytype))
```

All that code just to get `myarr[i]`... it doesn't feel right.

Comment: update: after running with this logic and doing some testing, the code is panicking unpredictably (in otherwords, undefined behavior). So the solution I posted doesn't even work.

Comment: The usual trick is to take a pointer to the first element of the array and turn this into a slice: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48756732/1256452

Comment: See also he documentation here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices

Comment: @torek / JimB, this is exactly what I was looking for. One of you should make an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is simply copied from the [CGo documentation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo).

> #### [Turning C arrays into Go slices](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices)
>
> C arrays are typically either null-terminated or have a length kept
> elsewhere.
>
> Go provides the following function to make a new Go byte slice from a
> C array:
>
> ```
> func C.GoBytes(cArray unsafe.Pointer, length C.int) []byte
> ```
>
> To create a Go slice backed by a C array (without copying the original
> data), one needs to acquire this length at runtime and use a type
> conversion to a pointer to a very big array and then slice it to the
> length that you want (also remember to set the cap if you're using Go
> 1.2 or later), for example (see http://play.golang.org/p/XuC0xqtAIC for a runnable example):
>
> ```golang
>         var theCArray *C.YourType = C.getTheArray()
>         length := C.getTheArrayLength()
>         slice := (*[1 << 28]C.YourType)(unsafe.Pointer(theCArray))[:length:length]
> ```
>
> It is important to keep in mind that the Go garbage collector will not
> interact with this data, and that if it is freed from the C side of
> things, the behavior of any Go code using the slice is
> nondeterministic.

The reason for the magic array size constant is described in [What does (*[1 << 30]C.YourType) do exactly in CGo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48756732/1256452)  The actual value of the constant, whether it's `1 << 30` or `1 << 28` or whatever, is not crucial, but it must be at least as large as the largest `length` value will be.

Comment: `C.GoBytes` has a massive issue in that it uses `C.int` for the size type, so if you ever find yourself with more than 2 gigs of data, it will overflow and the code panics.

Comment: @Xarn: that seems like something that should be filed as an issue with CGo... (Can now be addressed via generics, perhaps)