go lang: view []uint32 array as []uint8
what is the most efficient way in Go to view uint32 array as uint8 array?
for now my solution in go is quite clumsy and involves a lot of unnecessary binary arithmetic:
import "fmt"
func main(){
   xs := []uint32{0xff00ffff, 0x00aaaa00}
   n := len(xs)
   ys := new([]uint8, n*4)
   for i, x := range xs {
    j := i*4
    ys[j] = uint8(x >> 24)
    ys[j+1] = uint8(x >> 16)
    ys[j+2] = uint8(x >> 8)
    ys[j+3] = uint8(x)
  }
  fmt.Println(ys) // [255 0 255 255 0 170 170 0]
}

for comparison, in C it's just a pointer cast:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int xslen = 2;
    uint32_t xs[] = {0xff00ffff, 0x00aaaa00};
    int yslen = xslen*4;
    uint8_t* ys = (uint8_t*) xs;

    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < yslen; i++) { printf("%d ", ys[i]); }
    printf("]\n"); // [ 255 255 0 255 0 170 170 0 ]
    return 0;
}

EDIT: i know about unsafe.Pointer, however, it does not seem to solve the problem correctly
func main(){
 xs := []uint32{0xff00ffff, 0x00aaaa00}
 ys := (*(*[]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&xs)))
 fmt.Printf("%d %v \n", len(ys), ys) // 2 [255 255]
}


FYI the problem with your unsafe attempt, is that you are casting the slice header to a new type, whereas you need to cast the data in the underlying array. Prior to the unsafe functions in the answer below, the cast would have looked like https://stackoverflow.com/q/48756732/32880

Your code casts the slice header, which is dubious because the slice header contains the length of the slice which will need to be different (ie: 4 times larger) when viewing the data as uint8 rather than uint32.
Instead, you can use unsafe.SliceData and unsafe.Slice to deconstruct and reconstruct a new slice, resulting in this code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    xs := []uint32{0xff00ffff, 0x00aaaa00}
    ys := unsafe.Slice((*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(unsafe.SliceData(xs))), len(xs)*4)
    fmt.Printf("%d %v \n", len(ys), ys)
}

It's often a bad idea to use the unsafe package, but the above code is I think the best way to achieve what you want.

nice, it seems to be doing exactly what i want. but why is it a bad idea to use the unsafe package? does it produce double free error? can you point to some sort of concise explanation of how to use unsafe go?

@DaniilZuev, it’s no worse an idea than a pointer cast in C, but using unsafe bypasses one of Go’s major benefits, memory safety, allowing arbitrary memory access. It of course has its uses, you just should make sure it’s actually what you need.

@JimB you mean that i can mess up length recalculation? i don't think it's practically possible. seems safe enough for me as long as GC can deallocate it correctly.

@DaniilZuev, the length calculation and type conversion here are easy, and yes you are probably not going to mess it up. Once you use unsafe it of course allows much more complex things too, where mistakes are far more likely and the compiler can no longer prevent incorrect memory access.

Unsafe can introduce the possibility of runtime errors that may not be caught by the go runtime, such as unaligned accesses or out-of-bounds memory writes/reads. And you have to be careful that your code works with the GC. I don't think any of those problems apply to this code, but even if the code is correct you get extra mental toil from checking these things (rather than rely on go's guarantees).

One way to do this without unsafe is to use binary.encoding. You seem to be interpreting the array as littleendian, so:
target:=bytes.NewBuffer(make([]uint8,0,len(source)*4))
for _, x:=range source {
   binary.Write(target,binary.LittleEndian, x)
}
result:=target.Bytes()


i looked up the sources of binary.encoding and it basically does my current solution. maybe i've not stated that clearly enough, but i don't want array copying or binary arithmetic, i want a pointer cast, like in C.

No, you did not say you don't want array copying. That said, on a little-endian platform most of the bit artihmetic would be optimized away. This is the portable and safe way of doing it, if you prefer the unsafe route, @PaulHankin's answer works.
