# convert []string from Go to python list

Tags: python-3.x, go, cgo

I am trying to return **[]string** from golang to **list** in my python program. I am successfully able to convert go slice into c array from some of the references from stackoverflow.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492071/how-do-i-convert-a-go-array-of-strings-to-a-c-array-of-strings)

But I am not sure on how to convert back into python list.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Here are my code examples.

```
// example.go

package main

import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
)

//export Example
func Example() **C.char {
    // len of slice may be dynamic
    data := []string {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
    }

    cArray := C.malloc(C.size_t(len(data)) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0))))

    a := (*[1<<30 - 1]*C.char)(cArray)

    for i, value := range data {
        a[i] = C.CString(value)
    }

    return (**C.char)(cArray)
}

func main() {}
```

```
# example.py
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./example.so')

lib.Example.argtypes = None
lib.Example.restype = POINTER(c_char_p)
ret_value = lib.Example()

mylist = [value for value in ret_value.contents]
print(mylist)
```